# Equivalent implementation for <customErrors mode=RemoteOnly /> behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) site, I know that **customErrors** element provides information about custom error messages for an ASP.NET application. **RemoteOnly** value for **mode** attribute specifies that custom errors are shown only to the *remote clients*, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the *local host*.

At c# side, how can it be implemented, that some logic invokes only for remote clients, and other for local host (c# code which check this condition will be invoked from Global.asax.cs Application_Error level) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution.

I wasn't aware of the fact that `HttpRequest` type has `IsLocal` property. I've checked System.Web assembly using dotPeek for `System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection` implementation. I've found usage of `IsLocal` property for RemoteOnly mode. Its value indicates whether a request is from the local computer.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Context.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate Web.Config for a specific folder and override the main web config value for this specific folder config file

Comment: I don't want to play with web.config. I'd like to do similar functionality on my own at c# side.